# LSDateFormat is generating default date of 12/30/1899... how to fix?

Tags: date, coldfusion, if-statement

One of our databases has a page set up to print reports containing various geological information.  The database in question is a FoxPro DB, and contains a date field which in FoxPro is formatted mm/dd/yy.

There is a snippet of code in the report form

```
#LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")#
```

which is pulling the drill_date and converting it to the requested format, and in the process is taking all 1500~ records with no drill date and adding the default 12/30/1899 date.

Boss doesn't want the default date in the reports, but wants the full, formatted date (when it exists) on the reports because they do have some data that goes back to the early 1900s and they need the full century listed.

I'm trying to write an if/else statement that will create a variable, d_date, and store

```
 LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

if the field is filled,
else it will store an empty string " " if the date is empty.

```
<cfif (EMPTY(qLithHead.drill_date))>
     <cfset d_date=" ">
<cfelse>
     <cfset d_date=#LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")#>
</cfif>
```

and then in the date area of the report I'll simply call the d_date variable, whatever its value:

```
#d_date#
```

In any case, that's the general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm not at all sure of the CF syntax.

Any help you can offer is appreciated.

Thanks!  :)

Comment: Don't need # # in your cfset, just do: <cfset d_date= LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")>

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I've removed the ##.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coldfusion 9 has a isNull() function that returns a boolean:

```
<cfif isNull(qLithHead.drill_date)>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-3c4c0bb81223f1daffb-8000.html

Or, if you are not running CF9, you could try:

```
<cfif isDate(qLithHead.drill_date)>
```

or

```
<cfif Year(qLithHead.drill_date) EQ '1899'>
```

to get rid of the ugly timestamp

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jen!  This is the code I put in:          <cfif qLithHead.drill_date is not "">      
<cfset d_date=LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")> 
<cfelse>   
<cfset d_date=""> 
</cfif>                                                  unfortunately it's not changing the default date to an empty string when I call d_date.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting... when I swap the code around like so <cfif qLithHead.drill_date is not ""> <cfset d_date=""> <cfelse> <cfset d_date=LSDateFormat(qLithHead.drill_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")> </cfif> it replaces all dates with empty strings, including the default dates, indicating to me that the dates are not being stored as blank...I think? Any ideas?

Comment: Then drill_date must not be an empty string. A space maybe? Check the length. `<cfoutput>
length = #len(qLithHead.drill_date)#<br>
trimmed length = #len(trim(qLithHead.drill_date))#<br>
</cfoutput>` Btw: Do you really need LSDateFormat instead of just DateFormat?

Comment: Hi Leigh, I put your code through and got length = 26 d_date = 12/30/1899| And as far as LSDateFormat vs. DateFormat, I'm honestly not sure.  I'm trying to edit and fix existing code, and I'm very new to CF, dynamic HTML, etc.  LSDateFormat was in the existing code.

Comment: @Katie - Our posts clashed. What is the data type of your FoxPro db column (date/time, varchar, etc..)? Also try outputting the original and trimmed values too. `<cfoutput>
qLithHead.drill_date = |#qLithHead.drill_date#|<br>
length = #len(qLithHead.drill_date)#<br>
trimmed length = #len(trim(qLithHead.drill_date))#
d_date = #d_date#|<br>
</cfoutput>`

Comment: @Leigh - The FoxPro data is of type Date, width 8.  In the table itself, a blank shows up as / /.  Your second bit of code generates the following output:  qLithHead.drill_date = |{ts '1899-12-30 00:00:00'}|
length = 26
trimmed length = 26 d_date = 12/30/1899|

Comment: I replaced <cfif qLithHead.drill_date is ""> with <cfif qLithHead.drill_date is "{ts '1899-12-30 00:00:00'}"> and it got rid of the default dates!  Yay!  :)  Thanks so much!

Comment: OK, revised my answer try it again.

Comment: @Katie - Maybe it is a Foxpro peculiarity, but the '1899-12-30' value is odd. When you say a "blank" in the table, do you mean a db `NULL`? That is the standard way to indicate the value is missing. CF usually converts `NULL` values to an empty string - *not* 1899-12-30.

Comment: @Leigh - I think that's a default in the db. I have seen similar timestamps before. I was under the assumption that it was blank in the beginning as well.

Comment: @jen - If it is a default that would explain why the empty string does not work. Seems strange they did not just use `NULL` though .. @Katie - Just make sure your earliest data is 1900 then ;) Btw: LSDateFormat is for different locales. You probably do not need it. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6de1.html

Comment: @Leigh and @Jen, thanks both for your help. I think the 1899-12-30 date is a peculiarity to FoxPro, as detailed here, if I understand it right: http://www.ml-consult.co.uk/foxst-04.htm Sorry for the confusion! The dates are empty, not null. And I will check with my boss as to whether we need the LSDateFormat or not. Thanks again!

Comment: @Katie - Ah, yes that "empty" versus null distinction with dates does seem to be FP specific. Learn something new every day.